# Is there a javascript API which predicts that an ajax request is likely to be throttled?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am implementing part of a large javascript application where various scripts will be doing AJAX requests, often simultaneously.

I am considering implementing some helper class which can prioritize a stream of AJAX requests, and in some cases optimize by using a bulk api that the server understands instead of many small requests.

However I have a dilemma: if I just call e.g. `jquery.ajax()`, then I don't know if the request will be *sent straight away*, or be *throttled* by the browser (there may be requests executing and waiting for response already, sent from other components of the app). So, I don't really know when to do the bunching optimization, and when to just send a request straight away.

Is there a good way to ask the browser whether I'm going to be throttled in advance of issuing an AJAX request?

Comment: Is there a specific set limit to http requests before they start getting throttled? If so maybe you can keep track of the amount of requests being dispatched and see when you're reaching the limit?